# How to select all enteties grouped by common propertie without loop?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, loops

Is there any way to fatch all entities from table grouped by common property while loop?

Table **storage** looks like this

```
id         |  product_id   | category_id
-----------+-----------------------+--------------------------
1          |       1       | 15
2          |       2       | 17
3          |       3       | 18
4          |       4       | 17
5          |       5       | 15
6          |       6       | 17
7          |       7       | 18
```

and final result supposed to look like this

```
    id         |  product_id   | category_id
    -----------+-----------------------+--------------------------
    1          |       1       | 15
    2          |       2       | 17
    3          |       3       | 18
    4          |       5       | 15
    5          |       4       | 17
    6          |       7       | 18
    7          |       6       | 15
```

What i want is this:

Select **each** record grouped by category id. It means, if table size is 3200, i need to select all of 3200 records grouped by category id in ASC order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the values interleaved.  You can use `row_number()` in the `order by`:

```
select s.*
from storage s
order by row_number() over (partition by storage_id order by id),
         storage_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=477a555d2357d9af8f3888a93d8a9f2e) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

In older versions of MySQL, you can assign a sequential number within each group using variables and then use that for ordering:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             (@rn := if(@sid = storage_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@sid := storage_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from (select s.* from storage s order by storage_id, id) s cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @sid := -1) params
     ) s
order by seqnum, id;
```

The SQL Fiddle has both methods.

Comment: indeed that does the work, but it seems like my host has low version (5.7). I'm trying to use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html